# Mongodb- How to get data from a partition that was created by other user?

Tags: android, mongodb, realm

I am using Realm MongoDB for my android app, and I have a problem:

I have different users in my app, and each user has his "cards". The partition of each user's cards is:
"Card=userID".
So, I want to be able to send a card from one user to the other. I do it via a link that includes userID and specific cardID.

So my code looks something like:

```
    Realm.init(this);
    mainApp = new App(new AppConfiguration.Builder(APP_ID).defaultSyncErrorHandler((session, error) ->
            Log.e("TAG()", "Sync error: ${error.errorMessage}")
    ).build());

    //TEMP CODE
    String partition = "Card=611d7n582w36796ce34af106"; //test partition of another user

    if(mainApp.currentUser() != null) {
        SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(
                mainApp.currentUser(),
                partition)
                .build();

        Realm realmLinkCard = Realm.getInstance(config);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: cards found- " + realmLinkCard.where(Card.class).findAll().size());
    }
```

The last log always shows 0. I know there are cards for sure because if the user that created the corresponding partition is signed in then it does find the cards.

permissions are set to true for both read and write for the whole sync.

What can the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a Realm by a user who has a different partition.

Instead you can create a mongodb function and call it from your user.

Make your function here:

[image: realm functions]

Check here on [How to create a function](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/define-a-function/#create-a-new-function)

And call it by checking here on [How to call a function from client](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/examples/call-a-function/)

Quick example of a realm function:

```js
exports = async function funcName(partition) {
  const cluster = context.services.get('myclustername');
  const mycollection = cluster.db('mydbname').collection('mycollectionname');
  let result = [];

  try {
    result = mycollection.findOne({
      _partition: partition,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    result.push(e);
    return result;
  }

  return result;
};
```

To call it, please see above for the documentation as I'm not an Android developper.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I actually solved my problem.
The problem was with the Sync configuration, I added the line:
                .waitForInitialRemoteData()

which forced Realm to sync all data before moving on, because apparently realm synced the data in the background, and if I tried to get data that haven't been synced yet it will just show like it doesn't exist and that's was all the problem